# how to remove multiple parts from a video, using ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

how to remove multiple parts from a video?
for example i have a video of one minute and i want to delete following segments:

from second 0.0 to second 10.0
from second 20.0 to second 30.0
from second 40.0 to second 45.0

please remember i want to delete above mentioned segments, the output should not include these segments.
i have already tried all the answers, but they are all joining the trimmed segments, which i don't want.e.g:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=30[av];[0:a]atrim=duration=30[aa];[0:v]trim=start=40:end=50,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];[0:a]atrim=start=40:end=50,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];[0:v]trim=start=80,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[cv];[0:a]atrim=start=80,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ca];[av][aa][bv][ba][cv][ca]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

thank you.
note:(python version also accepted.)

Comment: Is the question about python? If not could you remove the tag?

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided concatenates the trimmed segments. To remove the segments from the video, you should invert your logic: instead of specifying the parts you want to remove, you specify the parts you want to keep.

From your requirement, you wish to retain:

1. 10.0s to 20.0s
2. 30.0s to 40.0s
3. 45.0s to the end of video

Here's how you can do it using FFmpeg:

```bash
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=10:end=20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=10:end=20,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=30:end=40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=30:end=40,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=45,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=45,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; \
 [v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" out.mp4
```

Also, based on your comment, when you want to work on mili seconds ranges like your example, I think this code can work for you:

```py
def create_ffmpeg_cmd(deleteRange, input_file, output_file):
    segments = []
    last_end = 0.0  # Start of video

    for start, end in deleteRange:
        segments.append((last_end, start))
        last_end = end

    segments.append((last_end, None))  # End of video

    filter_parts = []
    for idx, (start, end) in enumerate(segments):
        if end is None:
            video_segment = f"[0:v]trim=start={start},setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v{idx}];"
            audio_segment = f"[0:a]atrim=start={start},asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a{idx}];"
        else:
            video_segment = f"[0:v]trim=start={start}:end={end},setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v{idx}];"
            audio_segment = f"[0:a]atrim=start={start}:end={end},asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a{idx}];"
        filter_parts.extend([video_segment, audio_segment])

    filter_concat = "".join(filter_parts)
    filter_concat += "".join([f"[v{i}][a{i}]" for i in range(len(segments))])
    filter_concat += f"concat=n={len(segments)}:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"

    cmd = f"ffmpeg -i {input_file} -filter_complex \"{filter_concat}\" -map \"[outv]\" -map \"[outa]\" {output_file}"
    return cmd

deleteRange = [(40.12/1000, 46.583/1000), (51.312/1000, 53.229/1000), (128.055/1000, 130.536/1000)]
cmd = create_ffmpeg_cmd(deleteRange, "foo.mp4", "out.mp4")
print(cmd)
```

Comment: i can't because i receive ranges like: deleteRange= [(40.12, 46.583), (51.312, 53.229), (128.055, 130.536)], in "ms", any solution? these ranges i need to delete from the video.

Comment: I just edited the answer and added a part including python code to it. I think that might help you.

Comment: what if the deleRange also includes: (0.0, 10.2)

Comment: Then you just need to add this segment `(0.0, 10.2)` to `deleteRange` in the code.